# How can I use resque-web for rails api-only app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-api

I believe resque-web requires ActionView to work correctly. I have a rails api-only app. I plan to run the resque workers on a separate machine using a shared redis server.

How can I make resque-web work and still maintaining the app as lean as possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resque-web with rails api only mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580755/resque-web-with-rails-api-only-mode)