# resque-web with rails api only mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, resque

**1. What is the best way I can use resque-web with rails API-only mode?**

My application uses resque with four separate job servers fur running the queues. I have mounted resque-web and I run it on local machine. it works fine only to show me the information about workers and queues. However,
    if I try to 'retry failed' jobs or 'delete a queue', it gives me
    routing error.

**2. Is there any readymade way to expose all the routes used by resque-web as a json API?**

So that I can design my own JS front end for job monitoring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use resque-web for rails api-only app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233406/how-can-i-use-resque-web-for-rails-api-only-app)

Answer (score 0):

In an Rails "API-only" app, you can fix the routing errors when retrying failed jobs or deleting queues by adding these lines to `application.rb`:

```rb
config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/resque/resque-web/issues/142#issuecomment-446427655) for more details.